# Is a QSqlQueryModel the proper way to bind a table's field to a QListView?

Tags: qt

**Core question: is there a way to specify what field is displayed by a QListView?**

I have a db table with two fields: *id* and *keyword*

I wanted to display *keyword* in a `QListView` but was getting the `id` value, since that is the first field in the table. I ended up using a `QSqlQueryModel` and it works but I'm wondering if this is the standard way of doing this.

The user will be able to add additional keywords to the db, so in order to display the new data I need to do a new query. That might be kind of dopey. I tried switching to a `QTableView`  and `QSQLTableModel` but I don't need that functionality. Bad decision?

I'm setting up the `QSqlQueryModel > QListView` connection as follows.

```
 model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);
 model->setQuery("SELECT keyword FROM keywords",db);
 keywordListView->setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the column index of that field with `QSqlTableModel::fieldIndex`, and set it as the field to display by the view with `QListView::setModelColumn`.